# Showing incorrect sum in excel row sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Formula `=(N59 -O59 - P59 - R59)`

working fine for most rows but for some rows, the sum is 0 - but it is showing a strange value like **-7.27596E-12**

I have tried many thing but I don't know what I am missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because computer math isn't exact in decimal, so 0.1+0.9 is not necessarily exactly 1.0.  The notation "E-12" means "times ten to the minus twelfth," which is tiny.

Here's a [forum thread](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/excel-2010-displaying-0-as-an-infinitesimal-number-in-scientific-notation.18669/) on the subject, and here's the official [Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-handle-leading-zeros-and-precision-in-number-codes-57f15d52-5c75-4a67-ad35-394ae944d347).  If you change the cell format from General to Number, you can set how many digits you want.  E.g., if you select 2 digits, 0.001 or anything smaller will round down to display as 0.

[image]